# Sort counted distinct unique occurrences with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am wondering how to sort the following list in descending order of the most occurrences with linq:

```
ghj
def
abc
def
abc
abc
```

to:

```
abc
def
ghj
```

I am looking for the lambda expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string[] names = { "ghj", "def", "abc", "def", "abc", "abc" };

IEnumerable<string> query = names
   .GroupBy(s=>s) // groups identical strings into an IGrouping
   .OrderByDescending( group => group.Count()) // IGrouping is a collection, so you can count it
   .Select(group=>group.Key); // IGrouping has a Key, which is the thing you used to group with. In this case group.Key==group.First()==group.skip(1).First() ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the distinct list ordered by occurrences, use Group By:

```
var query = foo.GroupBy(xx => xx)
               .OrderByDescending(gg => gg.Count())
               .Select(gg => gg.Key);
// on your input returns:
// abc
// def
// ghj
```

Comment: I'm a big fan of the double-letter syntax for throw-away variables, although I have been trying to get rid of that habit since some other people dislike them. Glad to see I am not alone